# Selecting only the latest version in a group with a specific status

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

In a project I am working on I have the table you can see below. On the frontend I need to show only the records that are published grouped by the entity_id. For example, in the example below only id 1, 11, 16 and 19 should be shown. I have no idea how to make this query. I tried several things with subqueries etc but none of them work. I guess there should be a way to retrieve this data. What am I missing?

```
| id | revision   | entity_id   | status     
========================================
| 1  | 1          | 1           | published
| 2  | 2          | 1           | archived
| 3  | 1          | 2           | draft
| 4  | 2          | 2           | draft
| 5  | 3          | 2           | draft
| 6  | 4          | 2           | ready
| 7  | 5          | 2           | draft
| 8  | 6          | 2           | published
| 9  | 7          | 2           | published
| 10 | 8          | 2           | ready
| 11 | 9          | 2           | published
| 13 | 1          | 3           | draft
| 14 | 1          | 4           | draft
| 15 | 2          | 4           | draft
| 16 | 3          | 4           | published
| 18 | 1          | 5           | draft
| 19 | 2          | 5           | published
| 20 | 3          | 5           | draft
| 21 | 10         | 5           | archived
```

I created a DBFiddle to play around:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4UcjKhTvzzNQWL3Pfkfew4/1

**Note** It's not the same as [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column) since the answer there would select all the revisions that are published and not just the latest one.

Comment: which version of MySql are you using?

Comment: I am using version 5.7

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're after something like this...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS entities;

CREATE TABLE `entities` 
( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
, entity_id INT NOT NULL
, revision INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
, type enum('gym','trainer') 
, status enum('published','ready','draft','archived') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'draft'
, UNIQUE KEY entities_entity_id_revision_unique (entity_id,revision)
);


INSERT INTO entities
(id, entity_id, revision, type,status) VALUES
( 1,1, 1,'gym','published'),
( 2,1, 2,'gym','archived'),
( 3,2, 1,'gym','draft'),
( 4,2, 2,'gym','draft'),
( 5,2, 3,'gym','draft'),
( 6,2, 4,'gym','ready'),
( 7,2, 5,'gym','draft'),
( 8,2, 6,'gym','published'),
( 9,2, 7,'gym','published'),
(10,2, 8,'gym','ready'),
(11,2, 9,'gym','published'),
(13,3, 1,'gym','draft'),
(14,4, 1,'gym','draft'),
(15,4, 2,'gym','draft'),
(16,4, 3,'gym','published'),
(18,5, 1,'gym','draft'),
(19,5, 2,'gym','draft'),
(20,5, 3,'gym','draft'),
(21,5,10,'gym','published');
    
    
SELECT x.* 
  FROM entities x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT entity_id
            , MAX(revision) revision
         FROM entities
        WHERE status = 'published'
        GROUP
           BY entity_id
     ) y
    ON y.entity_id = x.entity_id
   AND y.revision = x.revision;
   
   +----+-----------+----------+------+-----------+
   | id | entity_id | revision | type | status    |
   +----+-----------+----------+------+-----------+
   |  1 |         1 |        1 | gym  | published |
   | 11 |         2 |        9 | gym  | published |
   | 16 |         4 |        3 | gym  | published |
   | 21 |         5 |       10 | gym  | published |
   +----+-----------+----------+------+-----------+
   4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need! Thanks! Is there also a way to remove the entire entity from the result set when the latest revision status is archived?

Comment: If  'archived' is always the latest revision (when it occurs) then it's trivial.

Answer (score 0):

It s almost the same as with the max value

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * 
FROM
`entities`
WHERE id IN
(SELECT MIN(id)id FROM
`entities`
WHERE  `status` = 'published'
GROUP BY `entity_id`);

| id  | entity_id | revision | type | status    | name | slug | short_description | description | address | phone | email | website | openinghours | images | thumbnail | pricerange | created_at          | updated_at          | deleted_at          |
| --- | --------- | -------- | ---- | --------- | ---- | ---- | ----------------- | ----------- | ------- | ----- | ----- | ------- | ------------ | ------ | --------- | ---------- | ------------------- | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 1   | 1         | 1        | gym  | published |      |      |                   |             |         |       |       |         |              |        |           |            | 2020-10-03 21:49:14 | 2020-10-03 21:49:14 |                     |
| 8   | 2         | 6        | gym  | published |      |      |                   |             |         |       |       |         |              |        |           |            | 2020-10-10 16:28:14 | 2020-10-10 16:28:15 |                     |
| 16  | 4         | 3        | gym  | published |      |      |                   |             |         |       |       |         |              |        |           |            | 2020-10-10 17:06:38 | 2020-10-10 17:06:53 | 2020-10-10 17:06:53 |
| 21  | 5         | 10       | gym  | published |      |      |                   |             |         |       |       |         |              |        |           |            | 2020-10-11 14:54:16 | 2020-10-11 14:54:16 |                     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4UcjKhTvzzNQWL3Pfkfew4/2)

If you have multiple rivision you can use max, as the id is always increase by every new revision this makes no difference at all

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * 
FROM
`entities`
WHERE (`entity_id` ,`revision`) IN
(SELECT `entity_id` ,MAX(`revision`)  FROM
`entities`
WHERE  `status` = 'published'
GROUP BY `entity_id`);

| id  | entity_id | revision | type | status    | name | slug | short_description | description | address | phone | email | website | openinghours | images | thumbnail | pricerange | created_at          | updated_at          | deleted_at          |
| --- | --------- | -------- | ---- | --------- | ---- | ---- | ----------------- | ----------- | ------- | ----- | ----- | ------- | ------------ | ------ | --------- | ---------- | ------------------- | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 1   | 1         | 1        | gym  | published |      |      |                   |             |         |       |       |         |              |        |           |            | 2020-10-03 21:49:14 | 2020-10-03 21:49:14 |                     |
| 11  | 2         | 9        | gym  | published |      |      |                   |             |         |       |       |         |              |        |           |            | 2020-10-10 16:48:20 | 2020-10-10 17:00:47 |                     |
| 16  | 4         | 3        | gym  | published |      |      |                   |             |         |       |       |         |              |        |           |            | 2020-10-10 17:06:38 | 2020-10-10 17:06:53 | 2020-10-10 17:06:53 |
| 21  | 5         | 10       | gym  | published |      |      |                   |             |         |       |       |         |              |        |           |            | 2020-10-11 14:54:16 | 2020-10-11 14:54:16 |                     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4UcjKhTvzzNQWL3Pfkfew4/4)

Comment: Is it possible to get something like this but not based on is but on revision

Comment: If you have multiple rivisions you can use max, as the id is always increase by every new revision this makes no difference at all and the other query is simpler

Answer (score 0):

You can also use over partition by.

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ENTITY_ID ORDER BY REVISION ASC) AS RN 
  FROM ENTITIES
WHERE STATUS = 'PUBLISHED') K WHERE RN =1



| id  | entity_id | revision | type | status    | name | slug | short_description | description | address | phone | email | website | openinghours | images | thumbnail | pricerange | created_at          | updated_at          | deleted_at          | RN  |
| --- | --------- | -------- | ---- | --------- | ---- | ---- | ----------------- | ----------- | ------- | ----- | ----- | ------- | ------------ | ------ | --------- | ---------- | ------------------- | ------------------- | ------------------- | --- |
| 1   | 1         | 1        | gym  | published |      |      |                   |             |         |       |       |         |              |        |           |            | 2020-10-03 21:49:14 | 2020-10-03 21:49:14 |                     | 1   |
| 8   | 2         | 6        | gym  | published |      |      |                   |             |         |       |       |         |              |        |           |            | 2020-10-10 16:28:14 | 2020-10-10 16:28:15 |                     | 1   |
| 16  | 4         | 3        | gym  | published |      |      |                   |             |         |       |       |         |              |        |           |            | 2020-10-10 17:06:38 | 2020-10-10 17:06:53 | 2020-10-10 17:06:53 | 1   |
| 21  | 5         | 10       | gym  | published |      |      |                   |             |         |       |       |         |              |        |           |            | 2020-10-11 14:54:16 | 2020-10-11 14:54:16 |                     | 1   |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4UcjKhTvzzNQWL3Pfkfew4/3)